# Confusion in VHDL code

Tags: vhdl, multiplication, digital-logic

I am trying to implement a recoding logic for a 32 bit multiplier in VHDL. Besides, the input bit vector (`x_in`) to be recoded, it has one extra input "one". The intent is when "one" is `'1'` the output should be `x_in` else if "one" is `'0'`, it should be twice `x_in`. And if "neg" is high then the output has to be inverted. Here is my VHDL code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;

package sum_vector_pkg is
    type partial_sum_array is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(32 downto 0);
end package;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use work.sum_vector_pkg.all;
use work.test.all;

entity multipleGenerator is 
    generic(
           constant WIDTH : integer := 32
    );
    port(
        x_in      : in std_logic_vector(WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        one       : in std_logic_vector(WIDTH/2 - 1 downto 0);
        multiple  : out partial_sum_array
    );
end entity multipleGenerator;

architecture logic of multipleGenerator is
    signal sum  : std_logic_vector(WIDTH downto 0);

begin
    gen : for i in 0 to WIDTH/2 - 1 generate
        process (one,sum,x_in) is begin
            case one(i) is
                when '0' => sum <= x_in & '0'; -- twice x_in
                when '1' => sum <= '0' & x_in; -- same as x_in
                when others => sum <= x"00000000" &'0';
            end case;
            multiple(i) <= sum;
            report "The sum is " & toString(sum) & " one(i) is " & toString(one(i)) & " x_in is " & toString(x_in);
        end process;
    end generate;
end architecture logic;
```

I am running it with the following testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use work.sum_vector_pkg.all;

entity tb_multipleGenerator is

end entity tb_multipleGenerator;

architecture logic of tb_multipleGenerator is

    component multipleGenerator
        generic(
           constant WIDTH : integer := 32
        );
        port(
            x_in      : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
            one       : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
            multiple  : out partial_sum_array
        );
    end component;

    signal x_tb        : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal one_tb      : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal multiple_tb : partial_sum_array;

begin
    process begin
        x_tb <= x"00000000";
        one_tb <= x"0000";
        wait for 200 ns;
        x_tb <= x"00001111";
        one_tb <= x"0011";
        wait;
    end process;

    u_mult: multipleGenerator
        generic map (
           WIDTH => 32
        )
        port map (
            x_in     => x_tb,   
            one      => one_tb,
            multiple => multiple_tb
        );
end architecture logic;
```

To check the output I am using the following package:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;

package test is
    function toString(v : std_logic_vector) return string;
    function toString(b : std_logic) return string;
end package;

package body test is 
    function toString(b : std_logic) return string is
        variable str : string(1 to 3);
        begin
            str := std_logic'image(b);
            return "" & str(2);
    end toString;

    function toString(v : std_logic_vector) return string is
        variable str    : string(1 to 1);
        variable strOut : string(1 to v'length);
        begin
            for i in 1 to v'length  loop
                str := toString(v(i-1));
                strOut(v'length - i + 1) := str(1);
            end loop;
            return strOut;
    end toString;
end test;
```

When I run the above code I get `'X'` in the output. Here is the sample output:

```
    Time: 200 ns  Iteration: 2  Region: /tb_multiplegenerator/u_mult/gen(12)
# ** Note: The sum is 0000000000000000000XX00XX00XX00XX one(i) is 0 x_in is 00000000000000000001000100010001
#    Time: 200 ns  Iteration: 2  Region: /tb_multiplegenerator/u_mult/gen(13)
# ** Note: The sum is 0000000000000000000XX00XX00XX00XX one(i) is 0 x_in is 00000000000000000001000100010001
#    Time: 200 ns  Iteration: 2  Region: /tb_multiplegenerator/u_mult/gen(14)
# ** Note: The sum is 0000000000000000000XX00XX00XX00XX one(i) is 0 x_in is 00000000000000000001000100010001
#    Time: 200 ns  Iteration: 2  Region: /tb_multiplegenerator/u_mult/gen(15)
```

Could someone please explain why this code is not working?

Comment: How about a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You could have dummied package mlite_pack with function bv_negate and provided a testbench. At the minimum supply a clear value for one and neg at the time of failure and shown how those report statements are generated. Your problem can't be replicated with what you have supplied.

Comment: @user1155120 I have updated the question and provided the testbench as well, please take a look, it should be replicable now.

Comment: Where is the "The sum is ..." output generated in your code?

Comment: I have a separate package for it which I have not included to make the question readable. But the output should be evident from the waveforms. But I can add if you need it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it should be generated somewhere in the `gen : for i in 0 to WIDTH/2 - 1 generate` loop, but there is nothing there.

Comment: Inside the generate block I have a process and in the last line of process, I have the following line:
`report "The sum is " & toString(sum) & " one(i) is " & toString(one(i)) & " x_in is " & toString(x_in);`
toString is a function defined in a separate package which converts the sum signal to string for printing.

Comment: In your testbench you set `x_tb <= x"00000000"` or `x_tb <= x"00001111"`. But the output says `x_in is 10001000100010000000000000000000`. Something is not right here as well.

Comment: I suggest you check whether your `toString` function is correct.

Comment: I have added the code and I am also seeing the 'X' in the waveforms in questasim so should be correct.

Comment: Try removing `std_logic_arith` and `std_logic_unsigned`, maybe they interfere with the normal `std_logic_vector` in unexpected ways. [You shouldn't be using them anyway](http://insights.sigasi.com/tech/deprecated-ieee-libraries.html).

Comment: Didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is already in your `multipleGenerator` entity. You define the signal `sum`, which you keep reusing in your `generate` statement. However, these assignments happen in parallel in VHDL. So in effect, you are assigning `sum` with 16 drivers!

But you don't need `sum` actually.

Cleaning up your code (and making it vhdl 2008)

std_logic_vector_vector_pkg.vhd:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package std_logic_vector_vector_pkg is
    type std_logic_vector_vector is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;
end package;
```

converter_pkg.vhd

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package converter_pkg is
    function to_string(slv : std_logic_vector) return string;
end package;

package body converter_pkg is
    function to_string(slv : std_logic_vector) return string is
        variable output : string(1 to slv'length) := (others => 'X');
        variable i_o : positive := 1;
    begin
        for i_s in slv'high downto slv'low loop
            output(i_o) := std_logic'image(slv(i_s))(2);
            i_o := i_o + 1;
        end loop;
        return output;
    end function;
end package body;
```

multipleGenerator.vhd

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.std_logic_vector_vector_pkg.all;
use work.converter_pkg.all;

entity multipleGenerator is 
    generic(
        WIDTH : integer := 32
    );
    port(
        x_in      : in std_logic_vector(WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        one       : in std_logic_vector(WIDTH/2 - 1 downto 0);
        multiple  : out std_logic_vector_vector(0 to WIDTH/2 - 1)(WIDTH downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of multipleGenerator is
begin
    gen : for i in 0 to WIDTH/2 - 1 generate
        multiple(i) <= '0' & x_in when one(i)='1' else x_in & '0';
    end generate;

    process(one)
    begin
        for i in 0 to WIDTH/2 - 1 loop 
            report "The sum is " & to_string(multiple(i)) &
                " one(" & integer'image(i) & ") is " & std_logic'image(one(i)) &
                " x_in is " & to_string(x_in);
        end loop;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

multipleGenerator_tb.vhd

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.std_logic_vector_vector_pkg.all;

entity multipleGenerator_tb is end entity;

architecture behavioral of multipleGenerator_tb is
    signal b        : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal one      : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal multiple : std_logic_vector_vector(0 to one'length-1)(x'length downto 0);
begin
    process
    begin
        x <= (others => '0');
        one <= (others => '0');
        wait for 200 ns;
        x <= x"00001111";
        one <= x"0011";
        wait;
    end process;

    u_mult: entity work.multipleGenerator
        generic map (
            WIDTH => x'length
        )
        port map (
            x_in     => x,   
            one      => one,
            multiple => multiple
        );
end architecture;
```